# Could not attach element img's src with location.protocol ,how to solve?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem on joint image src url as below:

```
  var pic = document.createElement('img');

    console.log('location.protocol only:' + location.protocol);
// print: location.protocol only:http:

    console.log('pic.src only:' + pic.src);
//print: nothing

    pic.src = location.protocol;
 
    console.log(' pic.src = location.protocol:' + pic.src);
    // print: location.protocol:http://localhost:8081/testbox/test.html`
```

it seems location.protocol automatically add `localhost:8081/testbox/test.html` on pic.src property,
but what I want is pic.src= http://+"imageSrc from server ".
if I keep doing  pic.src = location.protocol+imgSrc,
localhost:8081/testbox/test.html repeat twice in src, how do I solve this problem?
thanks!

I use to location.protocal.toString() try to change http:// into string but it does not work.

Comment: Just use pic.src = '/absolute/path.png'

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `pic.src` until you have complete path.
You can't just set part of the path and add rest of it later.

Once `pic.scr` receives data, it automatically converts it into full path if needed and proceeds download the image.

So assuming your have `imageSrc` variable with the path to the image, it would be something like this:

```
pic.src = location.protocol + "//" + imageSrc;
```

Comment: thanks, I set src=location.protocol + "//" +"localhost/upload/abc.jpg", then pic.src = location.protocol + "//"+src, it works. what a tricky property  pic.src is!